# A false output in multithreading in c?

Tags: c, multithreading, struct

I work with POSIX threads - multithreading in C. I want to create 5 threads and each threads work with only one struct variable. This is code of how I was work in so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct node {
  pthread_t tid;
  int id;
}node1;

void *func1(void *arg){
 node1 *nodes = arg;
 printf("Thread tid is %ld. The id : %d \n", (long)pthread_self(),nodes->id);
 return NULL;
}

int main(void){
int count = 5;
pthread_t th[count];
node1 nodes[count];
int i;

 for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
    nodes[i].id = i+1;
}
for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
    pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, func1, &nodes[i]);
}

for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
    pthread_join(th[i],NULL);
}
```

}

My output like this :

```
Thread tid is 0. The id is 0.
Thread tid is 1. The id is 0.
Thread tid is 2. The id is 0.
Thread tid is 3. The id is 0.
Thread tid is 4. The id is 0.
```

Thanks to @usr , I fix some errors of my code. But there is still one. Can you help me? I want to access id of nodes .  I want this output:

```
Thread tid is 0. The id is 1.
Thread tid is 1. The id is 2.
Thread tid is 2. The id is 3.
Thread tid is 3. The id is 4.
Thread tid is 4. The id is 5.
```

Comment: What do you think you're achieving with these two statements `node1 *nodes2 = (node1 *)arg; int count = sizeof(nodes2);`?

Comment: With first statement, I think I can create node elements . arg is node is sending from pthread_create function's 4th parameter. The second statement, I think I need the size of struct variable. So I used sizeof(nodes2). @nbro

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the entire `node1` array `nodes` to *all* the threads you create. If you want to each thread to work on just one thread, pass just the address of one element to each thread.

You are also not assigning anything to `id` memeber and pass it to threads and the threads read them uninitialized.

The thread functions need to call `pthread_exit()` or return a pointer - you are doing neither.

Here's  simplified version of your code with which you can build on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct node {
    pthread_t tid;
    int id;
}node1;

void *func1(void *arg){
   node1 *nodes = arg;
   printf("Thread tid is %ld. The id : %d \n", (long)pthread_self(),nodes->id);
   return NULL;
}

int main(void){
    int count = 5;
    pthread_t th[count];
    node1 nodes[count];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
        nodes[i].id = i;
        pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, func1, &nodes[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
        pthread_join(th[i],NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I can't acces nodes->id variable all of them 0. ?

Comment: In your code you are not initialized `id` member -- so `0` is the result of that (which is potentially undefined behaviour). You need to assign the id (see in my asnwer where I assign `id`s for each strcut.

Comment: node1 nodes[5];
    for (i=0; i<5; i++){
        nodes[i].id = i+1; }   I write this line before the for loop which is for creating threads. I edit my question. But still I don't get id variables. Do I have to write in like your ? Can you say me please ?

Comment: I add this line into the question

Comment: "node1 nodes[5]; for (i=0; i<5; i++){ nodes[i].id = i+1; } I write this line before the for loop which is for creating threads" which isn't in your question. So how do I know  that?! It doesn't have to be like I did. You can certainly initialize using a loop before passing them to the threads. But you are still passing `nodes` instead of passing each element of `nodes` - which I explained in the answer and the code demonstrates it.

Comment: okey, thanks your help . I fix some of the errors. But I can't access ids.